# Count on case Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

WE have below data in oracle database -

```
col1 col2 
Z1     A
Z1     B
Z2     A
Z2     C
Z3     A   
Z4     D
```

I want count on column two in such a way that -

Ouput -

```
col2  count
A      3     (Z1,Z2,Z3)
B      0     (Dont count if A is already present for record)
C      0
D      1      (Z4)
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Guys. But I could do this way -

```
select  count(case
            when (LISTAGG(col2,'-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col2)) like '%A%' then 1
            else null
        end) A,
        count(case
            when (LISTAGG(col2,'-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col2)) = 'B' then 1
            else null
        end) B,
        count(case
            when (LISTAGG(col2,'-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col2)) = 'C' then 1
            else null
        end)  C,
         count(case
            when (LISTAGG(col2,'-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col2)) = 'D' then 1
            else null
        end) D
from T
GROUP BY col1
```

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function `rank()` to achieve this.

```
select col2, count(case when rn = 1 then 1 end) cnt from (
select t.*,
    rank() over (partition by col1 order by case when col2 = 'A' then 1 else 2 end) rn
from table t
) group by col2;
```

Comment: I wont work as i want to give preference to A if present

Comment: @AnirudhD Could you just give it a go?

Comment: @AnirudhD It gives the exact answer you expect.

Comment: The idea is great, but add Z4/C to the data and you'll see the flaw. Replace your row_number clause with `rank() over (partition by col1 order by case when col2 = 'A' then 1 else 2 end) as rn` in order to solve it.

Comment: @Thorsten OMG. You're right. Updated. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The most general solution to your propositions where each key `COL1` is counted only in the first occurrence of the key `COL2` (in alphabetical order)

```
WITH tab AS
(
    SELECT 'Z1' col1, 'A' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Z1' col1, 'B' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Z2' col1, 'A' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Z2' col1, 'C' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Z3' col1, 'A' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Z4' col1, 'D' col2 FROM dual 
), tab2 as (
select COL1, COL2,
row_number() over (partition by COL1 order by COL2) as rn
from tab)
select COL1, COL2,
case when rn = 1 then 1 else 0 end is_valid
from tab2
order by 1,2
;

COL1 COL2   IS_VALID
---- ---- ----------
Z1   A             1 
Z1   B             0 
Z2   A             1 
Z2   C             0 
Z3   A             1 
Z4   D             1
```

The rest is simple group by with a SUM on IS_VALID

```
select COL2, sum(is_valid) cnt  from tab3 -- TAB3 is the above row source
group by COL2
order by 1

COL2        CNT
---- ----------
A             3 
B             0 
C             0 
D             1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your table name is `table_name`, One way to do it is using this:

```
WITH table_a AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT col1
    FROM table_name
    WHERE col2 = 'A'
)
SELECT col2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table_a) 
        THEN DECODE(col2, 'A', 1, 0) 
        ELSE 1 END
    ) count
FROM table_name
GROUP BY col2
ORDER BY col2;
```

Tested ok:

```
WITH table_name AS
(
    SELECT 'Z1' col1, 'A' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Z1' col1, 'B' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Z2' col1, 'A' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Z2' col1, 'C' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Z3' col1, 'A' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    --SELECT 'Z4' col1, 'B' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Z4' col1, 'D' col2 FROM dual 
)
, table_a AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT col1
    FROM table_name
    WHERE col2 = 'A'
)
SELECT col2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table_a) 
        THEN DECODE(col2, 'A', 1, 0) 
        ELSE 1 END
    ) count
FROM table_name
GROUP BY col2
ORDER BY col2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to count each record where either col2 is 'A' or no 'A' record exists for col1.

```
select 
  col2, 
  count(
    case 
      when col2 = 'A' or col1 not in (select col1 from table_name where col2 = 'A') then 1 
    end) as cnt
from table_name
group by col2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select   col2, count(case when col2 = col3 then 'x' end) as ct
from     ( select col2, min(col2) over (partition by col1) as col3
           from   your_table
         )
group by col2
order by col2   --  if needed
;
```

**Explanation**:

There is an inner query (a.k.a. "subquery") which returns one row for each row in the original table. It returns `col2` as is, and an additional (new) column, labeled `col3`. `col3` is calculated as the "first" or `min()` value of `col2` (in alphabetical order) for all the rows in the original table that have the same value in `col1` as the current row does. This is a typical example of an analytic function; `partition by col1` is similar to `group by col1` but it returns all the rows in the group (all the original rows from the original table) instead of one row per group, as would an aggregate function.

To see what the inner query does by itself, select it and run it in your favorite front-end. You may add `col1` to the select in the inner query - that will make what's going on in this query even clearer. You'll get the initial table, with one more column, `col3`, that shows the "min" `col2` for each value of `col1`. I didn't include `col1` in the subquery because I don't need it, but add it back to see what the subquery really does.

Then in the outer query I take the results from the inner query and I group by `col2`. For each `col2` I count just how many times it is equal to the "min" value of `col2` for the corresponding `col1` value. That's what the `case` expression does in the `count()` function; when `col2` is not equal to `col3`, then `case` returns `null` (by default) so the expression - and therefore the row - is not counted.

I should add that the query written this way assumes there are no duplicate `(col1, col2)` rows in the original table. If there are, then the inner subquery should select from a sub-subquery; line 3 of my code should be

```
from (select distinct col1, col2 from your_table)
```

Comment: Can you please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and  future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below script:

```
 SELECT A.COL2, NVL(B.CNT, 0) AS CNT
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COL2 FROM TET) A
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT COL2, COUNT(COL2) AS CNT
                   FROM (SELECT SUBSTR(F, 1, INSTR(F, ',') - 1) AS COL2,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTR(F, 1, INSTR(F, ',') - 1) ORDER BY SUBSTR(F, 1, INSTR(F, ',') - 1)) AS U
                           FROM (SELECT COL1,
                                        LISTAGG(COL2, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY COL2) || ',' AS F
                                   FROM TET
                                  GROUP BY COL1)) A
                  GROUP BY COL2) B
        ON A.COL2 = B.COL2
     ORDER BY A.COL2;
```